# Why can't I link nameservers in my DNS?

Tags: domain-name-system

I was looking into reselling domains. At the business I was looking, they didn't offer whitelabel nameservers. So I asked if I could just link their nameservers in my DNS. They said that it wasn't possible. I don't understand why.

To make my question more clear: let's say I have domain `A.net` with the nameservers `ns1.A.net` and `ns2.A.net`. I would like people to be able to use the nameserver `ns1.B.net` via my domain name, e.g. `Bns1.A.net`. Why can't I just add an `A` record in the DNS for `A.net`?

Comment: What I wonder is what the point of doing this is? Vanity?

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist ?

Comment: I merely wonder why you don't just use the canonical names for the nameservers, maintained by the service provider?

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist Because I want to use my own nameservers.

Comment: In that case I don't understand the question. I thought the question specifically was about using some other party's nameservers?

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist No, just how I can link nameservers via my DNS.

Comment: There may not be any point to argue this, but are you really saying that you are referring to yourself by "they" in the question?

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist No :/ why would I?

Comment: Because in your previous couple of comments you said that I was wrong in thinking that you were using nameservers run by a different party and that you wanted to use your own nameservers. Which to me comes off as very different from what the question says (unless "they" in the question is you, but then nothing makes sense).

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist Sorry, but I'm not following this anymore :P

Comment: I was just trying to get clarification if this whole exercise served a practical purpose or if it's just a vanity thing. If I ignore your comments, which stand in conflict with what the question says, my impression is that the motivation is purely vanity. Would I be wrong to think that?

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist >> Would I be wrong to think that? - Well, no idea. The world won't explode if it's unclear tho :)

Comment: It could benefit others that read the question to understand the purpose, though. It's a Q&A site, after all.

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist I think it's clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to do more than just create the A record under A.net.; you would also have to create a glue record for each nameserver via the registrar. Ie, You CAN do it.

That said, when your wholesale provider says you can't do that, they probably mean that it violates their ToS.  Ie, perhaps they meant MAY NOT instead of CAN NOT.

Comment: So if I create an `A` record and a glue record it should work?

Comment: Yes, it will work. However, if it does violate their ToS it may not be worth it to risk losing your account - probably safer to just setup a couple nameservers of your own on some VPSs or something.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will accept your answer, but first have to wait for the timer...

Comment: Other than them just not wanting you to do it, ignoring their warning could have operational impact in case they change IP addresses (and the address records for the canonical names) later on.

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist I am no longer using their services, I'm now using the services of another company where it's allowed to use whitelabel nameservers, hence why I asked this question :)